# How to redirect a subdirectory to an external url s3

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an old site which I am moving to s3, except some of the pages I am moving to another subdomain (not s3).  They have urls like:

`http://www.example.com/2015/09/07/some-url`

which I would like to redirect to a url like:

`http://subdomain.example.com/2015/09/07/some-url`

I can't seem to get it to work, here are my redirect rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>2015/09/07/some-url/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <Protocol>http</Protocol>
        <HostName>subdomain.example.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>2015/09/07/some-url/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Also, do I have to actually create empty directories in the s3 bucket for the rules to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need empty directories for this to work.  You probably do, however, want to remove the trailing slash.

```
<KeyPrefixEquals>2015/09/07/some-url/</KeyPrefixEquals>
```

...becomes...

```
<KeyPrefixEquals>2015/09/07/some-url</KeyPrefixEquals>
```

The trailing slash, if needed, is typically going to be added by the destination server if not supplied by the incoming request.

Also, you shouldn't need to set `<ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>` unless the value is changing.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

**Setting a Page Redirect from the REST API**
The following Amazon S3 API actions support the x-amz-website-redirect-location header in the request. Amazon S3 stores the header value in the object metadata as x-amz-website-redirect-location.

PUT Object

Initiate Multipart Upload

POST Object

PUT Object - Copy

When setting a page redirect, you can either keep or delete the object content. For example, suppose you have a page1.html object in your bucket.

To keep the content of page1.html and only redirect page requests, you can submit a PUT Object - Copy request to create a new page1.html object that uses the existing page1.html object as the source. In your request, you set the x-amz-website-redirect-location header. When the request is complete, you have the original page with its content unchanged, but Amazon S3 redirects any requests for the page to the redirect location that you specify.

To delete the content of the page1.html object and redirect requests for the page, you can send a PUT Object request to upload a zero-byte object that has the same object key:page1.html. In the PUT request, you set x-amz-website-redirect-location for page1.html to the new object. When the request is complete, page1.html has no content, and requests are redirected to the location that is specified by x-amz-website-redirect-location.

When you retrieve the object using the GET Object action, along with other object metadata, Amazon S3 returns the x-amz-website-redirect-location header in the response.